# PHP Session Security Flaw?

Tags: php, security, session

I'm new to php coding, and basically I'm creating a user panel where users login and from there they access their dashboard which lets them do things.

I'm using php sessions to do this, and basically at the top of the dashboard I put:

```
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:index.php");
```

This makes it so users who aren't logged in are re-directed to index.php.

The problem is that there is certain commands users can do from dashboard, like this:
/dashboard.php?reset=true

And doing these commands does not require active session for some reason. Anyone can just go to /dashboard.php?reset=true and reset everything, without an active session!

Does anybody know how to fix this security flaw which allows people to do this?

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a security flaw in your implementation of `/dashboard.php?reset=true` rather than PHP.  A session, by definition, requires the client to present a token with each request (either by cookie or query string).  That does not mean you have to look for it before taking action.  Could you post that bit of code (doing the reset) and the rest of your security checks?  The problem may lie there.

Comment: Missing `exit;`. And pretty sure that's not how [`session_is_registered`](http://php.net/session_is_registered) was to be used (note the past tense).

Comment: @Mario - isn't that the answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer :**
you could put the same code in the /dashboard.php? file

**Better** 
verfy if the user is an admin by declaring a sessionvariable.

when logged in before redirecting :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['is_admin']="yes" ;
```

In the "execution files" :

```
if(isset() && $_SESSION['is_admin'] == "yes")
{
  //do your thing
}
else
{
   echo : "you are not allowed to do that";
}
```

for more security tips : [link](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CHAPTER-5-SESSION-SECURITY-P804.html)
it will point out some security issues for you

Comment: as it was poited out by Dev don't forget to start the session

Answer (score 0):

I guess that by `reset` you mean password. Just get that part to ask them for the old password as well as the new old. And to stop robots use summat like CAPTCHA,

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `die` or `exit` or some other way of terminating after your `header()` call.  `header()` doesn't stop execution, so even though it's sending the Location: redirect, it's going to keep going down through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are using php 5.4.x

`session_is_registered` has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Use `isset($_SESSION['myusername'])` instead of `session_is_registered`

**Edit**

`exit` should always be put after redirecting from header, `die` will work too.

Comment: Does isset($_SESSION['myusername']) function still work on 5.3.0?

Comment: Thanks man it works great, this website is great I will stick around!